# Html how send data from one page to another page

Tags: javascript, php, html, json

I have a page name `index.php` In page index.php there is many url like

http://index2.php?user=2 ,http://index2.php?user=3  and so on.On my local host there is a page name `index2.php` and there is a text box with name user. I want whenever someone click on `http://index2.php?userid=2` on page one it automatically fill the data on next page input text with `2`

Comment: Please go read [ask]. _“I want”_ is not an actual question. Please explain what you have tried, and which part of this you are actually struggling with.

Comment: please sir answer if you have time please

Comment: U will get the answer even if you google your question title.

Comment: i search a lot but not find relevant result

Comment: what value do you want to pass, into wich file? show us some code please so we can try to make it work, instead of writing code for you

Answer (score 1):

When routing to the URL `http://index2.php/?user=2`, you can access the GET superglobal values as follows:

```
<?php $selected_user = $_GET['user'];/>
```

If you want this to be the value of your input you could do the following:

```
<input type="text" value="<?php echo $selected_user;?>">
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Ajax to send data from one page to another.

On Index.php Page

```
 $user=$_GET['user'];
 $.ajax({  
        type: 'POST',  
        url: 'next_page.php', 
        data: { user: <?php echo $_GET['user']; ?> },
        success: function(response) {
        }
    });
```

On next_page.php

```
$user= $_POST['user'];
echo $user;
```